# VTK : cluster a point cloud and get points of each cluster

Tags: vtk, point-clouds

I'am trying to cluster a point cloud with vtkEuclideanClusterExtraction, like that:

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> cloudPolyData = vtkSmartPointer < vtkPolyData>::New();
cloudPolyData->SetPoints(_PointCloudInput);
vtkNew<vtkEuclideanClusterExtraction> cluster;
cluster->SetInputData(cloudPolyData);
cluster->SetExtractionModeToAllClusters();
cluster->SetRadius(100);
cluster->Update();
```

where
`_PointCloudInput` is a `vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints>`

When I did
`cluster->GetNumberOfExtractedClusters()`, I got 104, so I guess it worked well.

Now, I'd like to know which point belongs to which cluster to create a list of `vtkPoints` for each cluster, so 104 lists.
How could I do that ?

I tried with `cluster->GetOutput()->GetPoints();` but I got all my cloud.

Comment: Looking at the docs, it seems like you need to set a list of seed points around with the class can build the clusters.